# error while executing a REST api script in Python : TypeError:'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, microsoft-teams

I am writing a code to create a team using REST api, I am using python 3.7 and  Pycharm IDE.
[I followed Microsoft TEAM official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta)
my Python code :

```
req = request.POST('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams')
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = {
'template@odata.bind': 
'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates/standard',
'displayName': 'My Sample Team',
'description': 'My Sample Team’s Description',
}
```

But I get following error :

```
TypeError:'dict' object is not callable
```

I am new to Python ,I tried searching through internet but I can't find much useful information.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `req = request.POST('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams')` to `req = requests.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams')` and things should be fine.